# Horizontal List That Evenly Divides Remaining Space via CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web app that uses Bootstrap. In this web app, I have a dynamically created list of items. An example of the items that are created is presented here:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li>home</li>
  <li>contact me</li>
  <li>a longer list item</li>
</ul>
```

When this gets rendered, its something like this:

```
+------------------------------------------------+
| +------+------------+--------------------+     |
| | home | contact me | a longer list item |     |
| +------+------------+--------------------+     |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

However, I'd like to figure out a way to make the items fill the width of the screen and be evenly distributed. In other words, I kind of want it like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+     |
| |           home           |        contact me        |    a longer list item    |     |
| +--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+     |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In the example above, each item is the same width and the text is centered within each cell. How do I do this in Bootstrap?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `display: flex`

```
.list-inline {
  display: flex;
}

.list-inline li {
  flex: 1;

  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Flexbox` as answered by Dan which I would recommend as well but if you are looking for `<=IE9 support`, you can use `table` layout.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.list-inline {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.list-inline li {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li>home</li>
  <li>contact me</li>
  <li>a longer list item</li>
</ul>
```